# How do I move focus with template refs in a v-for loop ( Vue 3 Composition API)?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using a button to show/hide more or fewer list items, and want to use a ref to focus on the first of the "more" items when the button is clicked (this would be the sixth item, or listItem[5]). In the vue Options API, this is relatively easy. But I cannot get it work with the Composition API. I see all of the refs listed for the component in vue devtools:

```
listItem:Array[12] (Ref)
0:<li>
1:<li>
2:<li>
3:<li>
4:<li>
5:<li>
6:<li>
7:<li>
8:<li>
9:<li>
10:<li>
11:<li>
```

When the button gets clicked, I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`. I am relatively new to the Composition API, and it almost feels like a Catch-22, where I want to reference something that doesn't really exist yet. What am I missing here?

My code

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const listItem = ref([])
const showAllCounties = ref(false)

const showhideItems = (index) => {
  if (!showAllCounties.value) {
    return index < 5
  } else {
    return true
  }
}

const showFullList = () => {

  document.activeElement.blur()
  showAllCounties.value = !showAllCounties.value
if (listItem) {
  console.log('yes') // returns 'yes'
console.dir(listItem) // shows proxy array with all 12 items
}

  const target = listItem[5]
  if (target) {
    target.value.focus()
    console.log('yes, ' +target)
   } else {
    console.log('no')
  }

  listItem[5].value.focus()

//also tried listItem.value[5].focus()

}

</script>


<template>
<ul>
 <li
  v-for="(county, index) in project.data.counties"
  v-show="showhideItems(index)"
  class="project-counties-list"
  ref="listItem"
  :key="county.id"
   >
  {{ county.county_name }}, {{ index }}
 </li>
</ul>
 <button type="button" @click="showFullList">{{ ButtonText }}</button>
</template>
```

I've also tried logging `listItem` and `listItem.value[5]` to the console in `onMounted()`.

Comment: on the first look, you forgot a `.value` in your condition `if (listItem) {` and  here `listItem[5]`.

Comment: That's what I just figured out! I didn't "forget" the condition; I misunderstood that you need to use `listItem.value[5]` instead of `listItem[5].value`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that took me forever to figure out. The big key was to use `listItem.value[5]` instead of not `listItem[5].value`. Lesson learned (I hope) about how to deal with ref arrays. I also needed `nextTick()` to get the focus moved -- plus I had forgotten to include the `tabindex` in my previous example. So:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, nextTick } from 'vue'
const listItem = ref([])

let showAllCounties = ref(false)

const showHideItems = (index) => {
  return showAllCounties.value
  ? true
  : index < 5
}

const showHideFullList = () => {
  showAllCounties.value = !showAllCounties.value
  nextTick(() => {
    const target = listItem.value[5]
    if (target) {
      target.focus()
    }
  })
}

const showMoreButtonText = computed(() => {
  return showAllCounties.value
    ? 'Show less'
    : 'Show more'
})
</script>

<template>
<ul>
<li
  v-for="(county, index) in project.data.counties"
  v-show="showHideItems(index)"
  :id="`li-${index}`"
  class="project-counties-list"
  ref="listItem"
  :key="county.id"
  :tabindex="index === 5 ? -1 : false"
>
  {{ county.county_name }}
</li>
 </ul>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="toggle"
    @click="showHideFullList"
  >{{ showMoreButtonText }}
  </button>
</template>
```

Comment: If you don't want to write `.value` everytime you can think about using [vue macros](https://vue-macros.sxzz.moe/features/reactivity-transform.html).